# two versions of numpy

Tags: numpy

My department has version < 1.4 version numpy isntalled in /usr/lib/somewhere/numpy. Since I don't have the permission to replace it with a new version. I installed numpy 1.5 in my home directory. However, later when I install scipy, it complained that the version in /usr/lib/somewhere/numpy has version < 1.4. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `sys.path` so that your numpy directory comes in front of the global numpy directory.

That way your version should be imported instead of the other version. If you really want to make sure that the other version isn't used than you can use `virtualenv` to get your own private environment with all of your own libraries.

Comment: virtualenv is such a nice tool!

Answer (score 3):

You should use virtualenv to create an environment isolated from system packages with the --no-site-packages option to avoid any conflicts with your system packages. You can then install numpy with pip or easy_install specifying the version you want. There are many tutorials out there about how to use virtualenv.